# Unable to access App Configuration with User Managed Identity in Java spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

I am facing issues connecting to azure app configuration with User Managed Identity.

- **The issue that I am getting is:**

  com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalAzureSDKException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.azure.identity.CredentialUnavailableException: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established, Network is unreachable: no further information.

I am using below dependency in my spring boot application:

```
implementation ('com.azure.spring:azure-spring-cloud-appconfiguration-config-web:2.11.0')
```

My bootstrap.yml looks like this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app-service
    version: 0.0.1
  cloud:
    azure:
      appconfiguration:
        enabled: ${APP_CONFIGURATION_ENABLED} // true
        managed-identity:
          client-id: ${AZURE_CLIENT_ID}  // some valid client_id, created on azure portal
        stores:
          - endpoint: ${AZURE_END_POINT} // some valid endpoint
```

Please note i have created sample configurations on my azure portal and also exported **AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, AZURE_TENANT_ID** properties as environment variables containing valid values.

I am using spring boot version 3.1.0 and have been following this doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/spring-cloud-starter-appconfiguration-config-readme?view=azure-java-stable

**The same set of configurations works fine in plain Java**, by creating beans explicitily like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TokenCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build();

        ConfigurationClient client = new ConfigurationClientBuilder()
                .credential(credential)
                .endpoint("same endpoint as used above")
                .buildClient();

        ConfigurationSetting retrievedSetting = client.getConfigurationSetting("/application/app-service/appconfig.appUrl", "local");

        System.out.println(retrievedSetting.toString()); // works fine
    }
}
```

but these configurations doesn't work well with spring boot 3.x.

Can anyone point what probably i am doing wrong or what could be the issue here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running the app locally or in Azure?

Comment: In the example where you create the configuration client explicitly, you are using DefaultAzureCredential which falls back to local user authentication if Managed Identity is not available so it might not be the same thing.

Comment: @juunas: on my localhost

Comment: Managed Identities don't work locally, only when running in Azure.

Comment: hi @juunas, thanks for your response. can you please elaborate bit more, why they doesn't work locally.

Comment: The way Managed Identity works is that it makes an HTTP request either to the instance metadata service endpoint (e.g. VMs) or a local endpoint (e.g. App Service), which then does authentication with Azure AD using certificate authentication. But those endpoints are only accessible from inside that Azure service, not from outside.

Comment: Thankyou @juunas, will try and let you know. thanks for your help.

Comment: You will most likely need to use user authentication locally. Since DefaultAzureCredential works, that would probably work :)

Comment: Hi @juunas, Its still not working on my aks. In order to make it work in spring boot. I have done below steps:

1) Added appconfig dependency as shown above.
2) Added bootstrap.yml with same content as above.
3) Exported AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, AZURE_TENANT_ID properties as environment variables containing valid values.

Comment: still getting:

/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fappconfig-xx.azconfig.io&client_id=some_valid_id HTTP/1.1: null}{Metadata: true}{User-Agent: azsdk-java-azure-identity/1.7.3 (17.0.6; Linux; 5.4.0-1101-azure)}
Class:s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection Method:log Line:141 --- sun.net.www.MessageHeader@529caa75 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work the code must be running in a process that has a managed identity. When you are running your spring boot application locally you do not have this.

The reason why the java code works it that it is using credentials of the logged on user.

To delpoy your spring boot application to Azure App Service see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/deploy-java-spring-boot-app-service-mysql/

Comment: Its still not working on my aks. In order to make it work in spring boot. I have done below steps: 1) Added appconfig dependency as shown above. 2) Added bootstrap.yml with same content as above. 3) Exported AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET, AZURE_TENANT_ID properties as environment variables containing valid values.

Comment: still getting: /metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fappconfig-xx.azconfig.io&client_id=some_valid_id HTTP/1.1: null}{Metadata: true}{User-Agent: azsdk-java-azure-identity/1.7.3 (17.0.6; Linux; 5.4.0-1101-azure)} Class:s.n.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection Method:log Line:141 --- sun.net.www.MessageHeader@529caa75 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established.

Comment: You need to enable Managed Identity on your AKS Cluster https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity